# How do I pre-record values in the upcoming jFrame's TextFields?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I'm new to the Java/MySQL connectivity, and I feel kinda stuck right now. So, I am doing my assignment on a Hospital Management System. But I do not know how to display an already recorded value in the TextField of the next jFrame; the [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4PRS.jpg) is my current jFrame, the [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eJ1j.jpg) is the next jFrame. I need the jTextFields to display values, like in the third image.

EDIT: The following jFrame occurs when the user clicks 'Patient Registration'

Comment: Here is the third image: [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvZ8s.jpg

Comment: Please add all images to the site, so your question doesn't depend on imgur keeping them.

Comment: Sorry about that, but because I am new here. I can't upload pics

Comment: Add image like this template: ![text](imagelink)

Comment: Yes I tried that, but I was limited to 2 links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `JTextField.setText(String)`

Comment: Hi, can you tell me where do I add the code? I am confused if I have to add it in the current or the upcoming jFrame? EDIT: I actually want that when the user clicks Patient Registration, the next jFrame must already fill in the selected values like in the third pic

Comment: How on earth can I know what your code looks like since you haven't included it?

Comment: Hello, really sorry for the misunderstanding... what I meant was where to put the code: in the current frame or in the upcoming frame, not where EXACTLY I must put it. I ask this as I have tried doing it for hours, and yet haven't got it right.

Comment: I'm guessing there's an `ActionListener` which is listening for clicks on the "patient registration" button. You'd likely put your code inside that event listener. Possibly you want to call some "setters" on the Patient Registration form before calling `setVisible(true)`